# Application not connection to sqlserver outside the firewall

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

So I have an application that connects to our SQLServer.
This works on any server behind the firewall just fine.

When i put it out on our live server, outside the firewall the connection to the sqlserver fails with this error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection 
to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance   
name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: 
SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I know this is due to the firewall though the network admin claims the firewall is allowing it through (has even gone to the point of saying "your doing it wrong")

What can I do to see where it is failing exactly to see if it really is the firewall and prove to him that it is. 
I am using the IP of the machine so it is not a DNS issue.
Any other ideas?

Comment: How are you connection to the SQL Server from the other side of the firewall - what sort of connection string are you using?

Comment: using 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

the connection string looks like(with private info deleted)
 
    "Data Source=0.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=Dealers;User ID=user;Password=password"

Comment: Are you able to ping the SQL Server box from the DMZ machine?  Can you `telnet 0.0.0.0 1433` (with the right IP, of course) from this machine?  I'm assuming that your SQL Server is configured to listen on port 1433 here, of course.

Comment: I can ping the sqlServer.. But I could NOT telnet to it I get an error
saying could not open connection to the host on port 1433: Connection failed.

Comment: Can you telnet to the SQL server from inside the firewall on port 1433?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all due respect, your admin is right by telling you you're doing it wrong, assuming if what you mean by "outside the firewall" means outside of your company's network. Something like a database server should never be exposed to external connections.

**Edit:** Never mind, this is a connection from the DMZ.

So the only thing I can think of is to try and telnet to that machine on port 1433 (while logged into the web server) and see if you get a connection error. You're not using SSPI so I don't think security would be the issue.

If telnet fails then you can take that to your network admin as proof that the problem is the firewall.

Comment: the webserver is in what he calls the DMZ it is the public facing website that MUST be accessed from the outside. The SQL Server is behind the firewall

Comment: I think the webserver is outside the firewall - and the SQL Server is inside the firewall.

Comment: @twal, ok, so this is still within the confines of the network. Fair enough, I thought this was something like a client connecting from the outside or something.

Comment: @kprobst you mean TCP port 1433 (not 433).  
telnet 1.2.3.4 1433  
This is probably best on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a named instance? Make sure SQL Browsing Service is running.

Usually when you connect to the default instance on your local server you use '(local)'. When it's a named instance you would use '(local)\InstanceName'. Or (local) is replaced by a host name or ipaddress.

When you use a named instance you could run into connection problems when trying to connect from a remote server.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean by named instance. So I don't know how to answer.

Comment: Ok i am never using local. I am always connecting to a remote server. It is not on the same machine. SQLserver is on a separate machine on the network.